# Count all pages in FastReport programmatically using Delphi

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I am using FastReport in Delphi 10.4. In the first page I need to tell the user the number of pages of the report. Of course, this number is not fixed - it could be any of:

> This report has 12 pages.
>
> This report has 23 pages.
>
> This report has 1 pages.

This is my report structure: in page 1 there is the field `mmoTermoAberturaDescricao`, which is the place I need to show the number of pages.
[image: report designer with a text object]

And this is the code where I set the text's object display text:

```
procedure ShowReport(frxReport: TfrxReport);
var
  AText: string;
begin
  AText := 'This report has 12 pages...';
  TfrxMemoView(frxReport.FindComponent('mmoTermoAberturaDescricao')).Text := AText;
  frxReport.ShowReport();
end;
```

But how can I show the actual number of pages? It has to be some kind of variable that I need to access...

Answer (score 1):

[You can use **system variables** in your text object](https://www.fast-report.com/public_download/docs/FRVCL/online/en/UserManual/en-US/Creating_reports/Displaying_expressions_with_the_help_of_the_Text_object.html), such as `[TOTALPAGES#]` (or `[TOTALPAGES]`). Either in the designer, or by code:

```
  AText := 'This report has [TOTALPAGES#] pages...';
```

Comment: And how do I prevent the bad wording for the case of `This report has 1 pages...`? How to access an actual variable so I'm able to choose between singular and plural?

Comment: Well, in my case the minimum number of total pages is 3, therefore it is not a problem for me. It also doesn't make sense to count when there is only one page. However, no idea how to do that because it finishes counting the total pages only after all the pages are printed, therefore, we would probably need `OnAfterPrint` or something like that I imagine.

Comment: Just do 'This report has [TOTALPAGES] page(s)

Comment: Or, maybe "Pages in this report: [TOTALPAGES]"